# How do I store http cookies in Javascript

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I want to store a subset of cookies in a Javascript (non-JQuery) equivalent of an associative array (which I know Javascript does not have).  In most languages that I'm familiar with this would be simple and along the lines of:-

```
cookiepart = cookieset.split('=');
cookie{cookiepart[0]} = cookiepart[1];
```

and it is then a simple case of:-

```
print(cookie{'session'});
```

The only way I've been able to achieve anything is by hardcoding the key ie:-

```
print(cookie.session);
```

which would entail having to use a switch statement along the lines of:-

```
switch(cookiepart[0]) {
  case 'session':
    cookie.session = cookiepart[1];
    break;
  case 'cookie2':
    cookie.cookie2 = cookiepart[1];
    break;
```

etc, etc

to populate the array which strikes me as being particularly inelegant.

Is there a better way?

Thanks to @DigitalDrifter this is almost working - but not quite.

The actual cookies are:-

```
redirect=1; sessionid=110430
```

My code is:-

```
let cookie = {};
let cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
cookies.forEach(c => {
        let [k, v] = c.split('=');
        Object.assign(cookie, {[k]: v});
});

alert("redirect : "+cookie.redirect);
alert("sessionid : "+cookie.sessionid);
```

`cookie.redirect` works fine and displays 1

but

`cookie.sessionid` displays undefined.  Why would that be?

Comment: You need [square bracket notation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/access-object-properties-javascript/) to access dynamic property names. And these days you're probably better using [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) than cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be better off using an object `{}` rather than an array here.

```js
let cookie = 'redirect=1; sessionid=110430';
let obj = {};

cookie.split(';').forEach(c => {
  let [k, v] = c.split('=').map(p => p.trim());
  Object.assign(obj, { [k]: v });
});


console.log(obj);

// outputs
// {
// "redirect": "1",
// "sessionid": "110430"
// }

console.log(obj.sessionid);

// outputs
// 110430
```

Comment: Thanks for this and I understand how this would work for a single cookie but how would I save say 3 cookies?

Comment: @DougConran Answer has been updated to reflect multiple cookies.

Comment: Thanks - This seems to be the answer.  ('Seems' because I've got a problem with my additional code at the moment but that is nothing to do with the answer).

Comment: I've updated my original question as I have a specific issue with one of the cookies using the suggested solution.

Comment: @DougConran It's because there's a space in front of `sessionid`, so you need to trim the string. See the update to my answer.

Comment: you are a star!! - Perfect answer and I still have a few hairs left.  Many thanks it all works well now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON, and just parse/stringify it. Also, I'm using local storage instead below.

I created two functions, so that way you could reuse them for any storage that you wanted.

```
function getStorage(key){
  str = localStorage.getItem(key) || "{}"
  return JSON.parse(str)
}

function setStorage(key, values){
   localStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(values))
}

str = getStorage("session")

str["test"] = 1

setStorage("session", str)

sessions = getStorage("session")

console.log(sessions["test"])
```

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to @DigitalDrifter, for anyone finding this question this is how I parse and save http cookies:-

```
let cookie = {};
let cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
cookies.forEach(c => {
        let [k, v] = c.split('=').map(p => p.trim());
        Object.assign(cookie, {[k]: v});
});
```